# Order of inserting elements into a 2D Vector in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I was practicing with C++ vectors, and found a problem when I was inserting elements into a 2D vector. In the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void fillVector(std::vector<std::vector<int> > &vec) {
    std::vector<int> list1;
    vec.push_back(list1);
    list1.push_back(1);
    list1.push_back(2);

    std::vector<int> list2;
    list2.push_back(3);
    list2.push_back(4);
    vec.push_back(list2);

    return;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > vect;
    fillVector(vect);

    std::cout << "vect size: " << vect.size() << std::endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << "vect in size: " << vect.at(i).size() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

the size of the first inner-list is 0, and the size of the second inner-list is 2. The only difference between `list1` and `list2` is that `list1` is first inserted into the `vec` 2D vector, before elements are inserted into it, while elements are first inserted into `list2`, before it is itself inserted into the 2D vector. After returning from the function, the elements inserted into `list1` are not printed, and its size remains the same.

I also attempted the first method with pointers instead,

```
std::vector<int> *list3 = new std::vector<int>();
vec.push_back(*list3);
list3->push_back(5);
list3->push_back(6);
```

However, the size of list3 when read from the calling function is still 0. 
I don't understand the difference between the two approaches. Why does the list have to appended after it's elements are inserted?

Comment: In first case, you need to change `list1.push_back(1); list1.push_back(2);` to `vec.back().push_back(1); vec.back().push_back(2);` otherwise you just add items to `list1` not `vec`.

Comment: Btw, your third solution (pointers) essentially doesn't work for the same reason first case doesn't work, since you `push_back()` the dereference of `list3` (just the values of list3).

Comment: Expanding on @DimChtz comment: when you put something into a `vector`, the `vector` stores a copy. Manipulating the original will have no effect on the copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vector.push_back(var)` makes a copy of `var` and inserts it into the vector. If you use `push_back()` on an empty list, it copies the empty list into the vector. Changing values in the list after this does not affect the copy that was inserted into the vector. This is because you are passing an actual object to `push_back()`, not a pointer to an object.

In the third example, you take a step in the right direction, but you de-reference the list before you pass it in, so `push_back()` makes a copy of what is at that address.

A simple solution to the problem is to always set your values before you insert the list into the vector.

If you wish to be able to change the values after the list is inserted, use `vect.at(i).push_back(val)` to add a value to the list at i. 
You could also make the vector contain pointers to other vectors, rather than the vectors themselves:

```
void fillVector(std::vector<std::vector<int> *> &vec) {
    std::vector<int> *list1 = new std::vector<int>(); //Remember to allocate memory since we're using pointers now
    list1->push_back(1);
    list1->push_back(2); 
    vec.push_back(list1); // Copy the pointer that is list1 into vec

    std::vector<int> *list2 = new std::vector<int>();
    vec.push_back(list2); // Copy the pointer that is list2 into vec
    list2->push_back(3);
    list2->push_back(4);
    return;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int> *> vect; // Vector of pointers to vectors
    fillVector(vect);

    std::cout << "vect size: " << vect.size() << std::endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << "vect in size: " << vect.at(i)->size() << std::endl;
    }
}
std::vector<std::vector<int> *> vec = new; // Vector of pointers
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining it so well. I like the solution of using pointers, they seem to be safer in this instance.

Comment: No worries,  remember to call `delete` when you finish,  since they're allocated with `new`

Comment: @iamseiko They aren't. Pointers in `vector`s is inviting a world of hell if you aren't prepared.

Comment: While it does work, I'd strongly suggest that you avoid this solution, because it requires that you do manual memory management - using `new`, which is a really big no-no.

Comment: If you're on c++11, you can use smart pointers (e.g std::unique_ptr) to avoid needing to take care deletion, but it is much simpler to operate on the vector elements directly.

Answer (score 2):

It almost seems like you are expecting python-like behavior? In any case, in C++ the distinction between references, pointers, and values is very important.

Your `fillVector` function has the right idea, as it takes a reference to a 2D vector `std::vector<std::vector<int> > &vec` - notice the `&`. However, when you create `list1`, and use `push_back()` right away

```
std::vector<int> list1;
vec.push_back(list1);
```

you are pushing the empty vector. `push_back()` will create a copy of this vector, which will be contained in `vect` (in `main`), and is a completely separate vector from `list1`.

At this point, if you want to access the vector already pushed, you can use `back()`, which returns a reference to the last element in the vector `vec`, that is, the last one pushed.

```
vec.back().push_back(1);
vec.back().push_back(2);
```

`list2` you modify before pushing back, so when the copy is made, it is made of the already modified vector. Your attempt with `list3` doens't really change things much, you dereference the pointer when you `push_back()` and a copy is made all the same. You could make `vect` be `std::vector<std::vector<int>*>`, but I'd strongly advice against it, as you have to do manual memory management - using `new`.

**Note:** While it's important for you to learn at some point, you should really try to avoid using pointers whenever possible, specially RAW pointers (look at [smart pointers](http://ootips.org/yonat/4dev/smart-pointers.html) instead). `std::vector`, and all other `std` containers I know of, do their own memory management - they are sure to do it more efficiently than you, and BUG FREE.

---

I would suggest that you simply work on the last vector pushed, as such:

```
void fillVector(std::vector<std::vector<int> > &vec) {
    vec.push_back(std::vector<int>());
    vec.back().push_back(1);
    vec.back().push_back(2);

    vec.push_back(std::vector<int>());
    vec.back().push_back(3);
    vec.back().push_back(4);
    return;
}
```

as you can see it's pretty much the same code repeated twice, so you can easily loop to get this or other results.

Answer (score 0):

When you put something into a `std::vector`, the `vector` stores a copy. Manipulating the original will have no effect on the copy. If you put a pointer into a `vector` of pointers the `vector` still stores a copy of the pointer. Both the original and the copy in the `vector` point at the same memory, so you can manipulate the referenced data and see a change in the referenced data.

So...

```
std::vector<int> list1;
vec.push_back(list1);
list1.push_back(1);
list1.push_back(2);
```

puts a copy of the empty`list1` into `vec`. Then copies of 1 and 2 are placed into the original `list1`. The copy of `list1` in `vec` is unaffected.

Writing this as

```
std::vector<int> list1;
vec.push_back(list1);
vec.back().push_back(1);
vec.back().push_back(2);
```

will correct this. As will a slightly cleaner version

```
vec.push_back(std::vector<int>());
vec.back().push_back(1);
vec.back().push_back(2);
```

as it doesn't have a waste `list1` hanging around cluttering up the scope.

And

```
vec.push_back(std::vector<int>{1,2});
```

will simplify even further if your compiler supports C++11 or better.

On the other hand...

```
std::vector<int> list2;
list2.push_back(3);
list2.push_back(4);
vec.push_back(list2);
```

puts copies of 3 and 4 into `list2` and then puts a copy of `list2`, complete with copies of the copies of 3 and 4.

Similar to above,

```
std::vector<int> list2{3,4};
vec.push_back(list2);
```

can reduce the workload.

Unfortunately your experiment with `list3` fails because while `list3` is a pointer `vec` does not hold a pointer, so `list3` is dereferenced and the `vector` referenced is copied. No pointer to the data `list3` references is stored, and `vec` contains an empty vector for the same reason as above.

```
std::vector<int> *list3 = new std::vector<int>();
vec.push_back(*list3);
list3->push_back(5);
list3->push_back(6);
```

A few notes on storing pointers in `vector`s

1. The `vector` only stores a copy of the pointer. The data pointed at must be scoped in such a way that it will not be destroyed before the `vector` is done with it. One solution is to dynamically allocate the storage.
2. (This applies to dynamically allocated pointers in general) If you dynamically allocate, sooner or later someone has to clean up the mess and `delete` those pointers. Look into [storing smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) rather than raw pointers and not storing pointers at all.
3. Familiarize yourself with [the Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three). `vector` looks after itself, but if you have two copies of the `vector` and you remove and delete a pointer from only one of them, you're going to have some debugging to do.